# need help to make a simple textbox validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

i am new in wpf and i try so many tutorial for make a easy validation using ValidationRule but nothing help me, i am so confused!
my problem is to implement all to my own project
i have a main window when clicking on button showen a dialog that ask for enter a number and i need to make validations on this number

this is the XAML of the dialog:

```
<Window x:Name="kInputWindow1" x:Class="FinalProject.kInputWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FinalProject"
     Title="Input" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">
<Grid Margin="15">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Source="question.jpg" Width="32" Height="32" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="20,0" />

    <Label Name="lblQuestion" Grid.Column="1">Question:</Label>
    <TextBox Name="txtAnswer" MinWidth="250" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="71,26,0.6,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" 
             ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="txtAnswer" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <DataErrorValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,15,0,0">
        <Button IsDefault="True" Name="btnDialogOk" Click="btnDialogOk_Click" MinWidth="60" Margin="0,0,10,0">_Ok</Button>
        <Button IsCancel="True" MinWidth="60">_Cancel</Button>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

this is the code:

```
public partial class kInputWindow : Window
{

    public kInputWindow(string question)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblQuestion.Content = question;
    }

    private void btnDialogOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAnswer.SelectAll();
        txtAnswer.Focus();
    }

    public string Answer
    {
        get { return txtAnswer.Text; }
    }

    private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }

}

public class CustomValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "No number was entered!");
        if (value.ToString().Contains(' '))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "No spaces allowed!");

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

i realy dont know what is missing for make its work

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: like its writen its not works...  there is no validation in the textbox and i dont know what is missing

Comment: another things?  the class "CustomValidationRule",  its need to be in a deferente class or its fine that i implement its inside the "kInputWindow" class

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors in your code:
1. You use DataErrorValidationRule instead of your own CustomValidationRule. So it should be like:

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
  <local:CustomValidationRule/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

2. You need to have correct Path on your Binding of Text property. Now you have binding to property "txtAnswer" but there is no such property in your TextBox.DataContext (and actually you don't have DataContext at all). The minimal example to make it work would be to add sample property to your Window and set Window as a DataContext of itself:

```
public partial class kInputWindow  : Window
{
  public string ResultText { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
   }
```

and then bind TextBox to this property:

```
<Binding Path="ResultText" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
             ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
```

Comment: Nikolay, thank you very much for the help, now its work but i have another 2 broblems: <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:CustomValidationRule/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>  showed that the name does not exist in the namespace  , and i got this line xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FinalProject".   the another thing, how can i prevent to click on "ok" button ,as long as there is an error validation

Comment: 1. "<Binding.ValidationRules> <local:CustomValidationRule/> </Binding.ValidationRules> showed that the name does not exist in the namespace" - you should use Namespace of your CustomValidationRule class here. Take a look at an article abour clr namespaces in xaml - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: 2. "how can i prevent to click on "ok" button ,as long as there is an error validation" - you can bind IsEnabled property of Button to Validation.Errors.Count of TextBox via converter from int to Visibility. You can read more about WPF converters here - http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: 1. I can't figure out what is relevant to me in the link you attached to me, and what I need to change. I did a search, I saw that solution:

    In VS, right click on your Solution -> Properties -> Configuration Properties

    A new dialog is opened, try to change the project configurations from Debug to Release or vice versa.
 i do that and when i  return back to debug the error dont showed any more but when i close VS and open it again the error showed again.  can you tryy help me what i need to change?  It seems that everything is configured correctly